# writing only one row after website scraping

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a list of all the golf courses in the USA through [this link](http://www.thegolfcourses.net/). I need to extract the name of the golf course, address, and the phone number. My script is suppose to extract all the data from the website but it looks like it only prints one row in my csv file. I noticed that when I print the "name" field it only prints once despite the `find_all` function. All I need is the data and not just one field from multiple links on the website.

How do I go about fixing my script so that it prints all the needed data into a CSV file.

Here is my script:

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

courses_list = []

for i in range(1):
 url="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/page/1?ls&location=California&orderby=title&radius=6750#038;location=California&orderby=title&radius=6750" #.format(i)
 r = requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)


g_data2=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"list"})

for item in g_data2:
  try:
    name= item.contents[7].find_all("a",{"class":"entry-title"})[0].text
    print name
  except:
        name=''
  try:
    phone= item.contents[7].find_all("p",{"class":"listing-phone"})[0].text
  except:
      phone=''
  try:
    address= item.contents[7].find_all("p",{"class":"listing-address"})[0].text
  except:
      address=''

  course=[name,phone,address]
  courses_list.append(course)


with open ('PGN_Final.csv','a') as file:
  writer=csv.writer(file)
  for row in courses_list:
          writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place and the code posted won't even execute. As written, the `courses_list.append()` call is *entirely outside the `for item in g_data2` loop* and will thus only be executed once, but since the rest of the indentation also is a mess I cannot tell for certain if that is your issue here.

Comment: I fixed it sorry about that.

Comment: There is just the one such `div` on that page.

Comment: So what do you suggest on how  I go about getting all of the data then?

Comment: Find better attributes? I see that there are `itemprop` attributes for example; the whole page is marked up with structured data (see https://schema.org/). Each entry is even in an `<article>` tag.

Comment: I am trying to use the article tag but I am having diffuclity on typing g_data2=findall. part. How should I got about that?

Comment: Why not try it out in an interactive Python session? `soup.find_all('article')` isn't that hard, is it?

Comment: for the item content will it still use the same format?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat implementation for your code. You can use the library `urllib2` instead of `requests`. And `bs4` works the same though.

```
import csv
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import *

url="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/page/1?ls&location=California&orderby=title&radius=6750#038;location=California&orderby=title&radius=6750" #.format(i)
r = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

courses_list = []
courses_list.append(("Course name","Phone Number","Address"))

names = soup.findAll('h2', attrs={'class':'entry-title'})
phones = soup.findAll('p', attrs={'class':'listing-phone'})
address = soup.findAll('p', attrs={'class':'listing-address'})
for na, ph, add in zip(names,phones, address):
    courses_list.append((na.text,ph.text,add.text))


with open ('PGN_Final.csv','a') as file:
    writer=csv.writer(file)
    for row in courses_list:
        writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
```